# Wordpress customize page not loading, gets 'Gayeway Timeout error'

Tags: php, wordpress

Using **Wordpress 4.0.1** , activated multisite for bolgging.
no. of themes are loaded. But when trying to **customize** themes, the `customize.php` page not loaded.
Its getting `504: Gateway Timeout Error`

*Any one know about this?*

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I figured out what the problem was with. I'll post the solution here, in case anyone else runs into it:

It might be a compatibility issue with one of the plugins, so I deactivated all of them, then I logged out and logged back in. Then I systematically activated each one, one by one. After I activated one, I'd check the customize page to see if it was the one causing the issue. I found that the `Network Latest Post` plugin is the one causing it to hang up for me.

Hope that helps someone!